# How do I reference a hidden input in a specifc form using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have a series of forms on a page that all have a recordId value as a *hidden* input. The form name/id is GPA-Entry-Form-1. I am trying to get the value of the hidden field this way:

```
$('#deleteThisGPAEntry-1').click(function() {
    var recordId = $('GPA-Entry-Form-1 #recordId').val();
    alert('You clicked me. ID: ' + recordId);   
    return false;
});
```

Unfortunately, I am doing something wrong. When the button is clicked the alert comes up with the message and the value of the recordId is showing as undefined.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks,

Josh

Comment: Missing # should be: $('#GPA-Entry-Form-1 #recordId').val(); assuming that's the form's id (name is done differently)

Comment: @Adam - cash in, my friend. Answerfy that comment!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot the pound sign! (Probably the most common jQuery mistake).

Assuming your form has GPA-Entry-Form-1 as the ID then use:

```
$('#GPA-Entry-Form-1 #recordId').val();
```

if it's the name then use:

```
$('form[name=GPA-Entry-Form-1] #recordId').val();
```

Either way you are using the descendent selector correctly. It should work.

Good Luck!

Answer (score 1):

> The form name/id is **GPA-Entry-Form-1**

You need to specify the form id by prefixing `#`:

```
var recordId = $('#GPA-Entry-Form-1 #recordId').val();
```